# Javascript tic tac toe onclick only once

Tags: javascript, onclick

Hello I am trying to finish my program. I am about two steps away from finishing but i'm stuck on how i can make it so once a box is clicked you can't click on it again until you restart the game.

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
var cell;
var nextTurn = "X";

function mouseMotion(ref, motion) {
    if (motion == 'over') {
        ref.style.borderColor = '#E00';
    } else if (motion == 'out') {
        ref.style.borderColor = '#CCC';
    }
}

function cellClick(cell) {
    if (cell.id == "cell1x1") {
        document.getElementById("cell1x1").innerHTML = "X";
        document.getElementById("cell1x1").innerHTML = nextTurn;
        playersTurn();

    } else if (cell.id == "cell1x2") {
        document.getElementById("cell1x2").innerHTML = "X";
        document.getElementById("cell1x2").innerHTML = nextTurn;
        playersTurn();
    } else if (cell.id == "cell1x3") {
        document.getElementById("cell1x3").innerHTML = "X";
        document.getElementById("cell1x3").innerHTML = nextTurn;
        playersTurn();
    } else if (cell.id == "cell2x1") {
        document.getElementById("cell2x1").innerHTML = "X";
        document.getElementById("cell2x1").innerHTML = nextTurn;
        playersTurn();
    } else if (cell.id == "cell2x2") {
        document.getElementById("cell2x2").innerHTML = "X";
        document.getElementById("cell2x2").innerHTML = nextTurn;
        playersTurn();
    } else if (cell.id == "cell2x3") {
        document.getElementById("cell2x3").innerHTML = "X";
        document.getElementById("cell2x3").innerHTML = nextTurn;
        playersTurn();
    } else if (cell.id == "cell3x1") {
        document.getElementById("cell3x1").innerHTML = "X";
        document.getElementById("cell3x1").innerHTML = nextTurn;
        playersTurn();
    } else if (cell.id == "cell3x2") {
        document.getElementById("cell3x2").innerHTML = "X";
        document.getElementById("cell3x2").innerHTML = nextTurn;
        playersTurn();
    } else if (cell.id == "cell3x3") {
        document.getElementById("cell3x3").innerHTML = "X";
        document.getElementById("cell3x3").innerHTML = nextTurn;
        playersTurn();

    }
}

function playersTurn() {
    if (nextTurn == 'X') {
        nextTurn = 'O';
    } else {
        nextTurn = 'X';
    }
}


function startNewGame() {
    location.reload(true);
}
```

Here's my HTML code:

```
<html>
<title>Tic Tac Toe</title>
<head>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="tictactoe.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tictactoestyle.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div id="playersTurn">&nbsp;</div>
 <div id="winnerIs"></div>
 <table id="tttTable" align="center">
 <tr>
 <td id="cell1x1" class="cell" onclick="cellClick(this);" onMouseOver="mouseMotion(this, 'over');" onMouseOut="mouseMotion(this, 'out');">&nbsp;</td>
 <td id="cell1x2" class="cell" onclick="cellClick(this);" onMouseOver="mouseMotion(this, 'over');" onMouseOut="mouseMotion(this, 'out');">&nbsp;</td>
 <td id="cell1x3" class="cell" onclick="cellClick(this);" onMouseOver="mouseMotion(this, 'over');" onMouseOut="mouseMotion(this, 'out');">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td id="cell2x1" class="cell" onclick="cellClick(this);" onMouseOver="mouseMotion(this, 'over');" onMouseOut="mouseMotion(this, 'out');">&nbsp;</td>
   <td id="cell2x2" class="cell" onclick="cellClick(this);" onMouseOver="mouseMotion(this, 'over');" onMouseOut="mouseMotion(this, 'out');">&nbsp;</td>
   <td id="cell2x3" class="cell" onclick="cellClick(this);" onMouseOver="mouseMotion(this, 'over');" onMouseOut="mouseMotion(this, 'out');">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td id="cell3x1" class="cell" onclick="cellClick(this);" onMouseOver="mouseMotion(this, 'over');" onMouseOut="mouseMotion(this, 'out');">&nbsp;</td>
  <td id="cell3x2" class="cell" onclick="cellClick(this);" onMouseOver="mouseMotion(this, 'over');" onMouseOut="mouseMotion(this, 'out');">&nbsp;</td>
  <td id="cell3x3" class="cell" onclick="cellClick(this);" onMouseOver="mouseMotion(this, 'over');" onMouseOut="mouseMotion(this, 'out');">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  <input id="newGameBtn" type="button" value="Start New Game" onclick="startNewGame();" />
</body>
</html>
```

I am still very new to writing javascript so please be gentle. So how would i make it so after a person clicks on a cell it won't let anyone else click it until you reset the game?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Why did you tag this as jQuery? You're not using jQuery anywhere!

Comment: You should use jQuery though, it's a pain to handle events with pure javascript :D

Comment: @wared Non-sense. He only needs click events which are perfectly easy in Vanilla Javascript. What he's doing with onmouseover/onmouseout should just be done with CSS instead of Javascript.

Comment: Not as easy as `.one('click'`. Ok, I'm a lazy guy :D

Comment: Yes, just as easy with `.onclick =`. Besides, a beginner should learn the *language*, not a framework built on it. It's terrible advice and it's the reason there are so many "web-developers" who know jack about Javascript.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13672931/flex-mobile-4-6-tic-tac-toe-computer-move/13676687#13676687 for a complete implementation done in javascript

Comment: @IngoBürk "It's terrible advice", there is surely worse. Take it easy, I didn't want to create a controversy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check if the box has already been clicked, at the top of your function:

```
function cellClick(cell) {
    if (cell.innerHTML === "X" || cell.innerHTML === "O") {
        return;
    }
    ...
```

By the way, your code is horribly verbose.  The following:

```
if (cell.id == "cell1x1") {
    document.getElementById("cell1x1").innerHTML = nextTurn;
```

could be compressed down to:

```
document.getElementById(cell.id).innerHTML = nextTurn;
```

which can be again compressed to:

```
cell.innerHTML = nextTurn;
```

There is no need for the `if` statements in what you have written above.

Comment: `==` or better yet `===`, **not** `=`

Comment: Thanks for the correction!  That would have been a tautology.

Comment: Your edit is wrong, too. He wants to set `innerHTML` to `nextTurn`, not to `"X"` (though I'll remove my downvote already)

Comment: Corrected.  I think we got there.  :)

Comment: And here's a fiddle incorporating those things (and moving hover color changes to css): http://jsfiddle.net/5jLDu/ The next step would be to not assign the onclick handlers in the HTML, but in the Javascript. But he's a beginner, so let's not do too much at once.

Comment: @IngoBürk thank you as well for giving me the jsfiddle to go with it.

Answer (score 0):

An easier way would be to use the DOM. Use that variable you pass to your function called `cell` in order to remove the onClick Attribute before doing anything else in the function, like so:

```
function cellClick(cell)
{
document.getElementById(cell).removeAttribute('onClick');
//and that's all you really need...
//then when you refresh and/or regenerate the table, 
//the onClick Attribute should come back.
}
```